# Allegro 5 "Has stopped working" when loading a font

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

Title says it all. I'm (trying to) load a font in Allegro 5. Running the code at the bottom of this post results in a blank white window opening (desired) but crashes with "TSAGAME.EXE has stopped working" (not desired). Command prompt returns with a random negative number

The "problem details" dialogue is here: http://pastebin.com/Vc89wfwy

I have tested the "font" variable (Between lines 24 and 25). It's not null.

## Directory tree of my project folder:

```
C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\TSAGAME>tree /F
C:.
│   allegro.log
│   main.cpp
│   Orbitron Black.ttf
│   pirulen.ttf
│   TSAGAME.cbp
│   TSAGAME.depend
│   TSAGAME.layout
│
├───bin
│   │   Orbitron Black.ttf
│   │
│   └───Debug
│           allegro-5.0.10-monolith-mt-debug.dll
│           Orbitron Black.ttf
│           TSAGAME.exe
│
└───obj
    │   Orbitron Black.ttf
    │
    └───Debug
            main.o
            Orbitron Black.ttf
```

## Code::Blocks - Build Options - Linker Settings>Link Libraries:

`C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\Game4TSA\allegro\allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.5.0\lib\liballegro-5.0.10-monolith-mt-debug.a`

## Code::Blocks - Build Options - Search Directories>Compiler:

`C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\Game4TSA\allegro\allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.5.0\include`

## main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_ttf.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>

#define ScreenWidth 800
#define ScreenHeight 600

int main()
{
al_init();
al_set_new_display_flags(ALLEGRO_WINDOWED);
ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = al_create_display(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
al_set_window_position(display, 200, 100);
al_set_window_title(display, "Neat a demo");
al_init_font_addon();
al_init_ttf_addon();

ALLEGRO_FONT *font = al_load_font("C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/TSAGAME/Orbitron Black.ttf", 10, 0);
al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(44, 117, 255), 0, 0, NULL, "www");
al_flip_display();
al_rest(10.0);
al_destroy_font(font);
al_destroy_display(display);

return 0;
}
```

Ideas? I've been digging for a while. To put it simply:
[xkcd, #979](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzNmw.png)

Comment: have you tried it with a different font? Also, that path looks odd to me ... any reason you have unix-style path separators in a windows-style path (i.e. should it be '\' instead of '/')?

Comment: Code::Blocks saw the Windows-style path separators as escape characters. Does it matter? I'm new to this.

Comment: @rcore will try a different font.

Comment: @rcore tried arial. No dice.

Comment: You need to escape backslashes in a string using `\\\`

Comment: @rcore Path is no longer an issue. Any problems you see?

Comment: Assuming your path is correct and `font` is really non-null, nothing stands out (aside from passing `NULL` instead of 0 as the flags argument to `al_draw_text`, but that shouldn't cause a total failure).